# In phoenix how do I manage static files?

Tags: angularjs, elixir, phoenix-framework

This seems like it should be very easy, but I can't seem to figure it out!

How do I get js I install with node into the vendored javascript? I've been doing crazy things like npm install, then copying angular.js from the node_modules into the web/static/vendor folder.

Comment: Have you found a standard way of integrating angular in phoenix ?

Answer (score 2):

Phoenix uses Brunch to handle static assets by default. There is a guide to handling static assets on the Phoenix Framework website here: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets

If you'd like to use something other than Brunch, you can, and there is a guide to doing so on the same page (the example used there is Webpack, but Phoenix is static-asset-compilation-agnostic so you can use whatever you prefer).

Comment: Sorry, I miscommunicated. I understand that, but I can only get brunch to compile things in the web/static/.  I want to install things like angular using npm, but then it goes into node_modules.  What is the correct way to get angular into the web/static folder?